# I keep getting DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unknown error 0x80040266. in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qmediaplayer

Is there a way to be able to play my mp3 (which contains Meta Data) file using QMediaPlayer?
I tried using 2 files (one with id3 tags and one without) the one without tags worked while the one with id3 tags didn't and gave me `DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unknown error 0x80040266`. So, is there a way to load files with id3 tags?

This is my code until now

```python
content = QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(mp3_file))
self.media = QMediaPlayer()
self.media.setMedia(content)
self.media.play()
```

Comment: Are you sure that you just removed the meta data, while keeping the media content ***completely*** intact (aka: no transcode)? How did you remove it? From where does that file come? Are you sure it's a standard mp3 file, and not another audio format that is just *named* with an `mp3` extension?

Comment: @musicamante I think I wasn't clear enough, I tried 2 mp3 files (one with id3 tags and one without). The one with no tags worked fine with no errors. But when I tried to play the one with the id3 tags it gave me ```DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unknown error 0x80040266```.

Comment: Then, the problem remains: remember that the file extension is just a *clue*: just because a file is named `something.mp3` it doesn't mean that it *is* an mp3 file. It could even be an ogg or mp4 file, a text document, an image, or even an executable. So, are you *completely* sure that the other file is an **actual** mp3 file? Be aware that it could even be a media container file (for instance, mkv, mp4 or ogg) that just contains an audio track: the fact that if you open it and your standard associated program *plays it* as an audio file is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @musicamante I used the code above to play both mp3 file, the one that contained metadata didn't play, so how do I make it play a mp3 file containing id3 tags. This is my only question. Also, I used yt-dlp to download the mp3 file

Comment: Please answer the question: are you *completely* sure that the file is actually an mp3 file? I've never used yt-dlp (I only used the original youtube-dl), and for what we know it could even be a bug on their part (the file is *named* as mp3, but it's not).

Comment: Yes, I am sure that it is an mp3. @musicamante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install K-Lite Codec Pack. It allows the player to be able to play files containing tags